# jquery function only works once through

Tags: jquery

I have a gallery type page with thumbnails.  When you click a thumb it loads the images having to do with that thumb into a hidden div, when they're done loading then div then slides open.  If you click another thumb it closes the div, clears the contents, loads the new content and then opens it again.  When you load the page you can click one thumb, then another, but if you go back to the first thumb and click the div won't open again, not sure why.  Thanks for any help on this.

I have a jsbin of it set up here http://jsbin.com/epawub/12/edit

the javascript I have set up for the thumbs is as follows:

```
var imgCount = 0;
var image=$('#images');

$('#klossviolins').click(function() {
  console.log("Loading...");
  $('#images').slideUp(500, function() {
    $("#images").empty().ready(function(){ 
        $("<img>", {
            src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/home.jpg"
        }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);
        $("<img>", {
            src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/services.jpg"
        }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);
    });     
  });
  $("#info_header").empty();
  $('#info_header').append("Kloss Violins Website");
});


$('#light_dance').click(function() {
  console.log("Loading...");
  $('#images').slideUp(500, function() {
    $("#images").empty().ready(function(){ 
        $("<img>", {
            src: "http://www.klossal.com/light_dance_1.jpg"
        }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);
        $("<img>", {
            src: "http://www.klossal.com/light_dance_var.png"
        }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);
        $("<img>", {
            src: "http://www.klossal.com/light_dance_2.jpg"
        }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);  
    });     
  });
  $("#info_header").empty();
  $('#info_header').append("Dancing With Light Series");
});




function onImage(e)
{
    console.log("Image loaded");
    imgCount++;

    if (imgCount == image.children().length)
    {
        image.slideDown(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: .ready doesn't do what you think it does in your code.

Comment: hmmm what does it do?

Comment: Absolutely nothing in your case, it just runs the code inside it immediately because the `document` is already ready.

Comment: is there a way to make it so the stuff in teh ready function doesn't run until teh empty has happened?

Comment: the empty is synchronous, nothing else can happen until it has happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must bind to the load event before you set the image's src value, otherwise the load event will trigger before you bind to it if the image is cached.

```
$("<img>").load(onImage).attr("src","http://www.klossal.com/light_dance_1.jpg").appendTo("#images");
// repeat for all similar
```

Also, make sure you reset imgCount back to 0.

```
...
if (imgCount == image.children().length)
{
    image.slideDown(500);
    imgCount = 0;
    ...
```

Comment: so I updated the jsbin and the same issue still happens, if I click the first them, it's fine, then the second, it's fine, then back to the first nothing happens.  http://jsbin.com/epawub/15/edit

Comment: You are never resetting imgCount back to 0, see edit http://jsbin.com/epawub/16/edit

Comment: awww that did it, you're the man, thanks so much for taking the time to help me